# Django Tutorial Error: Setting up the test client

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pycharm, django-testing

I'm on part 5 of the Django Tutorial and I've hit a snag. I'm trying to setup the test client with the following commands in the python shell:

```
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
setup_test_environment()
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mohitgupta/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 104, in setup_test_environment
    mail._original_email_backend = settings.EMAIL_BACKEND
  File "/Users/mohitgupta/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/mohitgupta/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting EMAIL_BACKEND, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I've looked into defining the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE with no real progress. Just a note that I'm using PyCharm as an IDE but I don't use the internal terminal they provide.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in previous sections of the tutorial, to start a shell in Django you should always do `./manage.py shell`, rather than starting Python directly. That sets up the environment for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have no clue why I abandoned that best practice (probably laziness) but after wasting an hour and a half I've learned my lesson :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it worked after I gave the command in the shell

```
import django
django.setup()
```